# lock go module for specific branch while update

Tags: go, go-modules

Dep has a very useful option - lock given a package for branch via constraints. You just specify a branch for a package and `dep ensure -update` update this package only within a selected branch.

In go modules I have to manually type go get -u package@branch and if I want to update all my modules by `go get -u` it will change `branch` in `package` to branch with most recent commit if any.

Is it possible to have dep-like behavior or automate this workflow?

Comment: Use `go get -u=patch` if you only want to update to patch releases, but not minor.

Comment: During the development process, I want a way to update all packages to the latest versions, but locked packages to the latest within the locked branch.

Answer (score 0):

A request for this feature is tracked at https://golang.org/issue/26964.